How to set a default icon theme for all users (including future users) in Ubuntu?
I want to set a specific icon theme (e.g., Papirus) as the default system-wide icon theme in Ubuntu.
The goal is:
All existing users should use this icon theme by default.
All new users should automatically have this icon theme applied when their accounts are created.

How can I configure the system to ensure the selected icon theme is applied globally for all users, including future ones?
the os is ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS x86_64
